# What is the syntax used in Angular such as: @NgModule and @Component and @Injectable? (using @ sign for declaring)

Tags: angular, typescript

For declaring modules and components and services, Angular uses syntax such as:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent
```

But what is it? I have never seen this syntax used in JavaScript.

Was it invented for Angular, or is it part of es7 or another specification?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript has a language feature called [`decorators`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). Angular leverages this feature to add custom framework features, such as `@Component`, services marked with `@Injectable`, and modules marked `@NgModule`.

> With the introduction of Classes in TypeScript and ES6, there now exist certain scenarios that require additional features to support annotating or modifying classes and class members. Decorators provide a way to add both annotations and a meta-programming syntax for class declarations and members. Decorators are a stage 2 proposal for JavaScript and are available as an experimental feature of TypeScript.

For example, the Angular documentation for [`Component`](https://angular.io/api/core/Component) states:

> Decorator that marks a class as an Angular component and provides configuration metadata that determines how the component should be processed, instantiated, and used at runtime.

## Additional Information

- [**Typescript Decorators**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)
- [**A deep dive on Angular decorators**](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-decorators)

Comment: Is usage of decorators common in typescript (i mean, does other typescript based frameworks use decorators mostly)?

Comment: @yaya the use of `@` symbol to add annotations is common in multiple programming languages. Java is most notable for their usage. They are useful when *convention* is preferred over *configuration*. They help reduce boilerplate source code and writing code just to configure things.

Answer (score 1):

These are decorators and related to typeScript

> A Decorator is a special kind of declaration that can be attached to a
>   class declaration, method, accessor, property, or parameter.
>   Decorators use the form @expression, where expression must evaluate to
>   a function that will be called at runtime with information about the
>   decorated declaration.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators